# Block type drives me nuts

Tags: objective-c, block

I have this code:

```
typedef void (^OutputBlockType) (void (^) (NSString*));

static  OutputBlockType outputBlock;


+(void) logMessage:(NSString*) msg {
 NSString* bla = @"bla"; 
 outputBlock(bla);
}
```

Granted, that the original code is a bit more complex. Still.. Xcode (4.3) is not happy with this code and throws me an

> Passing 'NSString *_*strong' to parameter of incompatible type 'void
>   (^*_strong)(NSString *__strong)';

message which, basically, tells me nothing at all. Does anyone have a clue as to what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message is more or less clear: you have declared your block as taking a block that takes a string argument, but you are passing it a string instead.

If you wanted a block that takes a string, here is a `typedef` for it:

```
typedef void (^OutputBlockType)(NSString*)
```

Comment: Yeah, I just saw this too.. I was always fixated on the second void being the return parameter and always oversaw that I had the return parameter already in the first void before the Block name. The block syntax really drives me nuts sometimes, to me, it seems, as if the definition and usage of a block type varies between when setting them as properties, or passing them or using them as new variable, etc. Sometimes the block name appears at the end (method definition) then in the middle (typedef), etc.. but thanks!!